# react mapbox gl: active item on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use
react-mapbox-gl 5.1 and
react-mapbox-gl-draw 2.0.4

```
const data = {
  features: data.map((layer) => {
    const { coordinates, geo_type } = layer

    return {
      geometry: {
        coordinates, // [32.4123131, 123131.2322]
        type: MAP_TYPE[geo_type], // Point | LineString | Polygon
      },
      properties: layer,
      type: 'Feature',
    }
  }),
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
}

<Map ref={ref}>
    <DrawControl
      onDrawUpdate={onDrawUpdate}
      onDrawCreate={onDrawCreate}
      controls={{
        point: true,
        line_string: true,
        polygon: true,
        trash: true,
        combine_features: false,
        uncombine_features: false,
      }}
    />
  <GeoJSONLayer data={data} {...geojsonStyles} />
</Map>
```

When I add elements through `<DrawControl />`, they are active and can be draggable
But all items added from data not active

Comment: through DrawControl

Comment: You need to ask an actual question. What do you need and where are you stuck?

Comment: not active items (point, line, poly)